# How to redirect URLs using chrome.webRequest API?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

background.js:

```js
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(function (details) {
    console.log(details.url);
    window.location.href = 'http://time.com/';
}, {urls: ['<all_urls>']}, []);
```

It shows all requests in the console when I visit a web site, but it doesn't redirect the site to time.com.

Additional Information:

I got error on background console here:

```
Error in event handler for webRequest.onHeadersReceived/1: ReferenceError: url is not defined at chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener.urls (chrome-extension://hkiajgmcjicgampfdeiiacbojlmdokob/background.js:5:8)
```

then... is there a way to see requests with console.log from time.com in this case?

I like to see request and don't need to redirect on Chrome window.
What I need is only request to see in background console.

Comment: `does not work` ... what happens? do you get an error? the thing is, `background.js` does not *have* a `window`

Answer (score 9):

[webRequest API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest) provides redirection functionality.

Add `webRequestBlocking`, `webRequest`, and host permissions in manifest.json:

```
"permissions" : [
    "webRequest",
    "webRequestBlocking",
    "http://www.example.com/*" /* or <all_urls> */
],
"background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
}
```

Intercept requests for the page itself (`main_frame`) and iframes (`sub_frame`) on the URLs you want to redirect (those should be declared in "permissions" shown above) in a `blocking` listener:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(function(details) {
    console.log(details.url);
    if (!details.url.startsWith('http://time.com/')) {
        return {redirectUrl: 'http://time.com'};
    }
}, {
    urls: ['http://www.example.com/*'], // or <all_urls>
    types: ['main_frame', 'sub_frame'],
}, [
    'blocking'
]);
```

To view the background console, [open it on chrome://extensions page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10258029).

Also, make sure to read the [extensions architecture](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch) article in the documentation: the background page is a totally separate page, not related to the web page, with its own context and its own URL like chrome-extension://blablabla/background.html which cannot be navigated to another URL.

Comment: 'webRequestBlocking' requires manifest version of 2 or lower. Is there an up-to-date solution?

Comment: In ManifestV3 you should use declarativeNetRequest, more info in the [migration guide](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/intro/mv3-migration/).